# How to create an android library/module with Proguard applied

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-library

### Scenario:

I need to create an android Library/Module for a client and I want to `Obfuscate` the library with `Proguard` so that the client could not extract or see the source code from Library. **How would I achieve this ?**

### Questions:

1- Is it possible to `Obfuscate` the library, so the user can not see the code ?

2- Is it possible to create an `APK` of Library with `Proguard` applied, and use that `APK` in other project.

---

**Any suggestions and solutions are appreciated.**

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried ? what are you struggling with ?

Comment: Thanks @a_local_nobody for quick response. I haven't tried anything yet, I'm just figuring this out. Because I know if I just put "minifiedEnabled  = true" in library module, it will not achieve the task. I want to provide Obfuscated Library module to my client but I'm blank about achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

First you've to specify the proguard rules for your module/library then you can define it either inside your project proguard rules or you can write these rules in your module level Proguard rules txt file.
You can see this [Medium](https://medium.com/native-mobile-bits/proguard-in-multi-module-android-app-custom-library-4893a2143e8b) article explaining the same.